# add "Chapter, Appendix" words to the autogenerated index

Tags: indexing

Hi I want to add the words Chapter: Appendix: etc... to the index, because the autoindex only shows the number of the chapter, i found this trick

```
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{Chapter }
\renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnum}{:}
\renewcommand{\cftchapnumwidth}{25mm}
```

this works ok but when exist appendix, the take the name of Chapter too in the index.

this is my code example:

```
\documentclass[%
    a4paper,
    openright,
    12pt
]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[%
  top     = 25mm, bottom     = 25mm,
  outer   = 25mm, inner      = 25mm,
  headsep = 25mm, headheight = 12pt,
  marginparwidth = 15mm ]{geometry}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{Chapter }
\renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnum}{:}
\renewcommand{\cftchapnumwidth}{25mm}


\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3} 

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
\begin{Huge}
\textsc{Title}
\end{Huge}
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}

\newpage
$\ $
\thispagestyle{empty}

\chapter*{}
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\begin{flushright}
\textit{Dedicated to my family}
\end{flushright}

\chapter*{Acknowledgements}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgements}
\markboth{Acknowledgements}{Acknowledgements}

Tank to all

\chapter*{Summary}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Summary}
\markboth{Summary}{Summary}

the summary

\tableofcontents


\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Figure List}
\listoffigures

\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Table List}
\listoftables


\chapter{Introduction}\label{cap.introduccion}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
Bla Bla Bla
\section{Section}
Bla bla bla
\subsection{Subsection1}
Ble ble ble
\subsubsection{SubSubSection}
Bli bli bli


\chapter{the name of chapter 1}\label{cap.nudo}
Bla bla bla bla

\chapter{the name of chapter 2}\label{cap.desenlace}

Bla bla bla bla

\appendix
\chapter{the name of appendix 1}\label{aped.A}
Bla bla bla bla

\chapter{the name of appendix 2}\label{aped.B}
Bla bla bla bla

\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\bibliographystyle{acm}
\bibliography{yyyy}

\end{document}
```

the result of the index is

```
Acknowledgements III
Summary V
Figure List VII
Table List IX
Chapter 1: Introduction 1
1.1 Section . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 1
1.1.1 Subsection1 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 1
1.1.1.1 SubSubSection . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 1
Chapter 2: the name of chapter 1 3
Chapter 3: the name of chapter 2 5
Chapter A: the name of appendix 1 7
Chapter B: the name of appendix 2 9
Bibliography
```

but i want something like

```
Acknowledgements III
Summary V
Figure List VII
Table List IX
Chapter 1: Introduction 1
1.1 Section . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 1
1.1.1 Subsection1 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 1
1.1.1.1 SubSubSection . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 1
Chapter 2: the name of chapter 1 3
Chapter 3: the name of chapter 2 5
Appendix
Appendix A: the name of appendix 1 7
Appendix B: the name of appendix 2 9
Bibliography
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: thanks for your interest I update my question with the full code examplI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the name in front of the chapter number by resetting it to `\appendixname`:

```
\documentclass[%
    a4paper,
    openright,
    12pt
]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[%
  top     = 25mm, bottom     = 25mm,
  outer   = 25mm, inner      = 25mm,
  headsep = 25mm, headheight = 12pt,
  marginparwidth = 15mm ]{geometry}

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{emptypage}

\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{\chaptername\ }
\renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnum}{:}
\renewcommand{\cftchapnumwidth}{30mm}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3} 

\begin{document}

\frontmatter\pagenumbering{Roman}% for uppercase Roman numerals

\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
\Huge
\textsc{Title}
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}

\begin{flushright}
\textit{Dedicated to my family}
\end{flushright}

\chapter{Acknowledgements}

Thanks to all

\chapter{Summary}

the summary

\tableofcontents

\listoffigures

\listoftables

\mainmatter

\chapter{Introduction}\label{cap.introduccion}
Bla Bla Bla
\section{Section}
Bla bla bla
\subsection{Subsection1}
Ble ble ble
\subsubsection{SubSubSection}
Bli bli bli


\chapter{the name of chapter 1}\label{cap.nudo}
Bla bla bla bla

\chapter{the name of chapter 2}\label{cap.desenlace}

Bla bla bla bla

\appendix
%%% change \cftchappresnum here!
\addtocontents{toc}{%
  \protect\renewcommand\protect\cftchappresnum{\appendixname\ }%
}

\chapter{the name of appendix 1}\label{aped.A}
Bla bla bla bla

\chapter{the name of appendix 2}\label{aped.B}
Bla bla bla bla

\bibliographystyle{acm}
\bibliography{xampl}

\end{document}
```

I've made also some fixes to your code.

1. Always use the `titles` option to `tocloft` unless you have good reasons not to
2. With `tocbibind` the lists and the bibliography automatically go in the table of contents
3. With `emptypage` blank pages added by `\cleardoublepage` (that's implicit in `\chapter`) are completely blank
4. `\Huge` is a command and not an environment
5. When in `\frontmatter`, `\chapter` does not produce numbers

[image]